# This question is now closed - please refresh the page for updated status

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, hyperlinks, error-message

If you are reading a question which needs a close vote, and you click close but the question has already been closed, this message pops up:

[image: message]

There should be a link to refresh the page where the text "refresh" is, just as when you are automatically logged into a different exchange or in a few other situations.

Comment: F5 is quicker to press anyway...

Comment: Why not automated refresh?

Comment: An automated refresh could affect a comment in progress? I think there is another question about automated refreshes but that seems a little invasive.

Comment: Typically users have their right hand on the mouse, and left hand on the keyboard with the index finger on "F" (if their hand is even on the keyboard). Having just clicked on "close" the mouse should be almost directly on the popout message, which seems to be quicker to reach than having to look down and press f5.  Also, the popout message being derived from a click event feels like it would naturally benefit from having a click event solution.